# Does Shapely support serialization of GeoJSON with empty and non-empty coordinate sequences?

Tags: python, shapely

The `shapely.geometry.shape` method will fail with an `IndexError` if a `Multi[Point|LineString|Polygon]` has an empty coordinate sequence, and I am curious if this is the intended functionality, note the Shapely version is `1.7.1`.  An MRE:

```
from shapely.geometry import multilinestring, shape

multipoint = {
    "type": "MultiPoint",
    "coordinates": [
        [0, 0],
        [],
    ],
}
shape(multipoint) # fails

multilinestring = {
    "type": "MultiLineString",
    "coordinates": [
        [[0, 0], [1, 0], [1, 1], [0, 1]],
        [],
    ],
}
shape(multilinestring) # fails

multipolygon = {
    "type": "MultiPolygon",
    "coordinates": [
        [[[0, 0], [1, 0], [1, 1], [0, 1], [0, 0]]],
        [],
    ],
}
shape(multipolygon) # fails
```

This seems to only occur if some are empty, if *all* are empty, the method works fine:

```
multipoint = {
    "type": "MultiPoint",
    "coordinates": [
        [],
        [],
    ],
}
shape(multipoint) # succeeds
```

Apologies in advance if this is the wrong place to ask this question, but there seems to be no Shapely users group and the official documentation directs here.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if it's normal. When you try to validate the GeoJSON with GeoJSONHint (NPM package), it fails. You can bypass the issue by cleaning the invalid geometries with the following:

```py
from shapely.geometry import multilinestring, shape

multipoint = {
    "type": "MultiPoint",
    "coordinates": [
        [0, 0],
        [],
    ],
}
multipoint['coordinates'] = [i for i in multipoint['coordinates'] if len(i) > 0]
shape(multipoint)

multilinestring = {
    "type": "MultiLineString",
    "coordinates": [
        [[0, 0], [1, 0], [1, 1], [0, 1]],
        [],
    ],
}
multilinestring['coordinates'] = [i for i in multilinestring['coordinates'] if len(i) > 0]
shape(multilinestring)

multipolygon = {
    "type": "MultiPolygon",
    "coordinates": [
        [[[0, 0], [1, 0], [1, 1], [0, 1], [0, 0]]],
        [],
    ],
}
multipolygon['coordinates'] = [i for i in multipolygon['coordinates'] if len(i) > 0]
shape(multipolygon)
```

Answer (score 2):

By the GeoJSON specification https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7946

- GeoJSON processors MAY interpret Geometry objects with
  empty "coordinates" arrays as null objects.
- It is possible for this array (GeometryCollection) to be empty.
- It is possible for this array (FeatureCollection) to be empty.

Coordinates array can be empty, but it does not seem to be allowed that the coordinate array has empty Positions.

The https://geojsonlint.com/ site validates totally empty MultiPoint

```
{
    "type": "MultiPoint",
    "coordinates": [
      
     ]
}
```

but not if there is also an empty Position

```
{
    "type": "MultiPoint",
    "coordinates": [
      []
     ]
}
```

This gives an error `position must have 2 or more elements`

With a non-empty position GeoJSON validates again

```
{
    "type": "MultiPoint",
    "coordinates": [
      [1, 2]
     ]
}
```